# Detect offers (image, price and description) in catalogue page

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect the offers on a page in an offer-catalogue.

Example pages:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
One offer consists of a price, a description and an image. I have marked an offer on each page with a red square.

Am I in over my head?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to detect the text (Via OCR) and the respective objects (via Object Recognition), as you suggested; separately and then try associate the images to the nearest text.

What you could also try would be to train a neural network to detect the both, but i do not know if that's easily possible.

Comment: Use adaptive thresholding to detect shapes of food

Comment: Try to associate the text and objects by position could possibly be an option. At least one I would be comfortable giving a shot.. If it would yield any actual results, I don't know.
It must be a neural network, the app I was referring to is using. They are able to detect all offers in a "square-like fashion" really impressively. However, I dont't think, that is something I would be comfortable throwing myself into. I think, I was hoping for it to be a more known problem. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: @SilverMonkey  ^

Comment: @qwr I'm not completely sure, how that would help me detect offers, though. But to detect the different food items it may be useful. I will look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem will require a lot of work using different technologies. I'll try to write a basic step-by-step process that you could choose to follow. I'd like to point out that this would not return a very high level of accuracy and would depend on how accurate each component is.

1. Extract contours from images: Opencv has a simple tutorial on contouring. Try to find the right number of iterations for the morphological transforms so that the image and the text next to it gets clubbed as one contour
2. Use OCR to extract text from these contours: Tesseract OCR is probably the best option you have. You might have to convert your image to binary or grayscale as a pre-processing step so improve your results.
3. Make a corpus which determines which text corresponds to a discount: Something as simple as a python list should do. Make a list of key words that indicate a promotional offer/discount. Map your OCR results to this corpus to determine if the text is talking about an offer.

I'm sorry but I cannot make out the small logos next to the descriptions in your images. If any small stamp/logo corresponds to a discount, you would try using template matching techniques also.